# Calculating how many minutes there are between two times

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview in my application which holds start and finish times.  I want to calculate the number of minutes between these two times.  So far I have got:

```
var varFinish = tsTable.Rows[intCellRow]["Finish Time"];
TimeSpan varTime = (DateTime)varFinish - (DateTime)varValue;
int intMinutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(varTime);
```

But the last line won't compile because it says I am using invalid arguments for the Timespan constructor.  I've researched quite a bit about how to calculate the number of minutes between two times, but I'm hitting a bit of a brick wall.  Can someone please advise me on the best way to achieve my objective.

EDIT/

Now my code is as follows:

```
var varFinish = tsTable.Rows[intCellRow]["Finish Time"];
TimeSpan varTime = (DateTime)varFinish - (DateTime)varValue;
int intMinutes = (int)varTime.TotalMinutes;
```

But I am getting an invalid cast on the second line.  Both varFinish and varValue are times e.g. 10:00 and 8:00 say.  So not sure why they won't cast to type DateTime?

Comment: If varFinish is a string, you can't cast a string to a DateTime. You need to use DateTime.Parse(...). Even then, it will imply today's date if there is no date in varFinish.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Try this

```
DateTime startTime = varValue
DateTime endTime = varTime

TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract ( startTime );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (minutes): " + span.TotalMinutes );
```

Edit:
If are you trying 'span.Minutes', this will return only the minutes of timespan [0~59], to return sum of all minutes from this interval, just use 'span.TotalMinutes'.

Comment: This is a good answer, but gives *0* on span.Minutes when difference between two times is greater than 1 hour (i.e. 60 minutes or more)

Comment: @MalikAsif. I just tried this with a span of 61 minutes and I get 1 hour and 1 minute, as expected. If the span was exactly 60 minutes, then yes, minutes would be zero. Were you thinking of `TotalMinutes()`?

Comment: Yes @Jim exactly, that is what i was talking about. The point mentioned is that the question was about total number of minutes.

Comment: NOT TRUE. `span.Minutes` returns a number [0..59]. Use `span.TotalMinutes` instead

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. As per the other comments, it doesn't solve the question properly.

Comment: @tjmoore thanks for the feedback, I agree with you. I answered the original question back in Jan 2012, after which the question was edited. I occasionally get downvotes for this answer, probably because most people are reading the answer 5 years after the original un-edited question was asked.

Answer (score 37):

```
double minutes = varTime.TotalMinutes;
int minutesRounded = (int)Math.Round(varTime.TotalMinutes);
```

[TimeSpan.TotalMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx): The total number of minutes represented by this instance.

Comment: Yes TotalMinutes is what i was looking for. Thank you very much ^_^

Comment: int minutesRounded = (int)Math.Round(minutes);

Answer (score 11):

In your quesion code you are using `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` incorrectly. Please see the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromminutes.aspx) for TimeSpan.FromMinutes, which gives the following method signature:

```
public static TimeSpan FromMinutes(double value)
```

hence, the following code won't compile

```
var intMinutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(varTime); // won't compile
```

Instead, you can use the [TimeSpan.TotalMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx) property to perform this arithmetic. For instance:

```
TimeSpan varTime = (DateTime)varFinish - (DateTime)varValue; 
double fractionalMinutes = varTime.TotalMinutes;
int wholeMinutes = (int)fractionalMinutes;
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to query the `TotalMinutes` property like this `varTime.TotalMinutes`

Answer (score 1):

If the difference between endTime and startTime is **greater than or equal to 60 Minutes** , the statement:`endTime.Subtract(startTime).Minutes;` will always return `(minutesDifference % 60)`. Obviously which is not desired when we are only talking about minutes (not hours here). 
Here are some of the ways if you want to get `total number of minutes`(in different typecasts):

```
// Default value that is returned is of type *double* 
double double_minutes = endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalMinutes; 
int integer_minutes = (int)endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalMinutes; 
long long_minutes = (long)endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalMinutes; 
string string_minutes = (string)endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalMinutes;
```