# Get minutes and seconds from timespan

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the minutes and seconds from a timespan. My two dates for example are
`2021-09-08 20:15:46.98Z` and `2021-09-08 20:18:32.65Z`. What I would like to do is return a decimal value that represents the time difference in minutes and seconds. From this example I would like to return `2.46` rounded (as in 2m 46s), however when I try something like:

```
TimeSpan span = (end - start); // Where end/start are the example dates
var time = (span.TotalMilliseconds/1000/60);
```

The result is `2.761166666666667`

Is the calculation I am doing incorrect?

Comment: 2.761167 is 2 minutes 46 seconds.  So if you wanted that to display as `2.46` you would probably have to parse the minute and second components together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the `subtract` method [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9017567/16987771)?

It looks like you're getting a correct decimal, just not in minutes and seconds since 46 seconds is about 76% of a minute.

Comment: Subtract seems to be the correct method and returns `00:02:45.6700000,` however I would like to return that as a decimal (rounded to the next decimal number 2.46)

Comment: @dwewers, the result of subtract is the same as minus `-`, is not it?

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman for some reason using subtract seems to get the correct answer, whereas I was getting `2.761166666666667` with `-`

Comment: Forgot to mark this as an answer as this is the method I used, `Timespan span = end.Subtract(start)`

Answer (score 5):

Your calculation is correct, You can try this as well (it will give the same result)

```
var t1 = DateTime.Parse("2021-09-08 20:15:46.98Z");
var t2 = DateTime.Parse("2021-09-08 20:18:32.65Z");
var diff = t2 - t1;
var diffDouble = diff.TotalMinutes; // double 2.7611666666666665
diffDouble = double.Parse($"{diff.TotalMinutes:F2}"); // double 2.76
```

> I would like to return 2.46

```cs
var diffStr = $"{diff.Minutes}.{(diff.Milliseconds >= 500 ? diff.Seconds + 1 : diff.Seconds)}"; // 2.46
diffDouble = double.Parse(diffStr); // 2.46
```

Comment: @ewerspej's answer is the correct one.  `TimeSpan.Minutes` and `TimeSpan.Seconds` give you what you probably expect (though I'd go for `TimeSpan.TotalMinutes` and `TimeSpan.Seconds`)

Comment: @Flydog57, the issue is that it won't return 4.6 but 4.5.. Milliseconds should be taken into account

Comment: If that's the case, add 50 ms to the TimeSpan before doing the calculation. That's cleaner than doing calculations with `double`s. It's a _poor man's rounding_ trick

Comment: @Flydog57, Could you write your solution after `var diff = t2-t1` here the comments please?

Comment: I mistyped 500 as 50 in my comment. I've added an answer with some explanation

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print it as **2.46**, you can do this:

```cs
TimeSpan span = (end - start);
Console.WriteLine($"{span.Minutes}.{span.Seconds}");
```

Alternative:

```cs
TimeSpan span = (end - start);
Console.WriteLine("{mm.ss}", span);
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-6.0

By the way, your math is correct. You're just not getting it as minutes and seconds, but as a decimal number.

Comment: You probably want `TotalMinutes` and not `Minutes`.  That way if the TimeSpan is > 1 minute (say 72 seconds), you will get 72 minutes and and the remaining seconds (in this case 46).

Comment: If that's what @dwewers wants. Indeed it can also be `TotalMinutes`, if hours are supposed to be included. Hint: You probably meant to say "TimeSpan > 1 hour (say 72 minutes) ..."

Answer (score 1):

The value you get is correct. If you want it in minutes and seconds separately, you can get it like as below

```
var minutes = Math.Floor(span.TotalSeconds / 60);
var seconds = Math.Ceiling(span.TotalSeconds % 60);
```

The `Ceiling` method is used just to round it to the next integer.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
DateTime start = DateTime.Parse("2021-09-08 20:15:46.98Z");
DateTime end = DateTime.Parse("2021-09-08 20:18:32.65Z");

TimeSpan timeSpan = end - start;
Console.WriteLine(timeSpan.ToString("mm':'ss"));
```

Output:

```
02:45
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use the *poor man's rounding*; adding half of the minimum precision you care about.  In this case, 500 milliseconds.

```
const int halfASecondInMilliseconds = 500;
const string time1str = "2021-09-08 20:15:46.98Z";
const string time2str = "2021-09-08 20:18:32.65Z";

var time1 = DateTime.Parse(time1str);
var time2 = DateTime.Parse(time2str);

var rawDiff = time2 - time1;
var roundedDiff = rawDiff + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(halfASecondInMilliseconds);

Console.WriteLine($"Time Diff: {Math.Floor(roundedDiff.TotalMinutes)}:{roundedDiff.Seconds}");
```

This results in:

```
Time Diff: 2:46
```

This does traditional rounding (halfway rounds up).  So, between `2:45.000` and `2:45.499`, you end up with a value of `2:45.500` and `2:45.999`.  That will end up showing as `2:45`.  Between `2:45.500` and `2:45.999`, you end up with `2:46.000` and `2:46.499`, resulting in `2:46`.